# Collation conflict in Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Want to set Collation in Select statement in SQL.

I have below SQL query for which I get error :
**Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.**

I have idea for setting collation for joins, in this case I dont have idea.

Below is the SQL Query for which I am trying to set **COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI**,

```
SET @ColumnNames_CSV_Responses_Smoker_Retail = ' ';
SELECT @ColumnNames_CSV_Responses_Smoker_Retail = COALESCE(@ColumnNames_CSV_Responses_Smoker_Retail, '') +
                                                  CASE WHEN QuestionType IN (2, 3, 4)
                                                        AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                                    FROM Optiontable
                                                                    WHERE Option_Code = '1001'
                                                                      AND Optiontable.Question_ID = Question.QuestionID) THEN 'dbo.ReplaceBrandIDWithCode(''' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + ''',[' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + ']) AS [' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + '],'
                                                       WHEN QuestionType IN (3) THEN 'REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM([' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + '])),'' '', ''#'') AS [' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + '],'
                                                       WHEN QuestionType IN (4) THEN 'REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM([' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + '])),1, LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM([' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + ']))) - 1),''^'', ''#''),'','','''') AS [' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + '],'
                                                       ELSE 'REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM([' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + '])),'','', '' '') AS [' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + '],'
                                                  END
FROM Question
WHERE CAST(QuestionID AS varchar)IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                     WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name)
ORDER BY QuestionSeqNumber;
```

Any Help will be Appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Does this query return different collations? `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation'), DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation');`

Comment: You realise that `[' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + ']` isn't injection proof, right? Just like a single quote (`'`) can be escaped, so too can a right bracket (`]`).

Comment: Hi @DanGuzman query returns same collations

Comment: What about the `question` and `optiontable` table column collations? `EXEC sp_help 'Question';`

Comment: Hi @EzLo I did put COLLATE on both side, then also it gives error

Comment: I can't see that you're referencing any other databases in the query, which leads to be believe that some columns have a different collation to others. Does `SELECT COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (N'Question',N'Optiontable')
  AND COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL;` return more than 1 row by any chance?

Comment: It shows error on the COALESCE(  )..    Line

Comment: @Larnu it gives me Latin1_General_CI_AI

Comment: I feel like we're missing something here then. CAn you include the DDL of your objects in the question please, and some sample data so that we can replicate the problem?

Comment: @Larnu most of the columns have Latin1_General_CI_AI collation, which is different from database collation